# Http Request and PHP POST/GET VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, post, httprequest

I have a few PHP websites that are posting 2 fields to me from a form.
I want to collect these values using VB.Net and assign them to a variable.

In PHP its simple, one of the values being posted is called id

```
$value = $_POST['id'];
```

What is the process in VB.Net, i have tried the following.

```
Dim value as String = Request.Form("id")
OR
Dim value as String = Request.QueryString("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpRequest.QueryString:Gets the collection of HTTP query string variables.

`Dim value as String = Request.QueryString("id")` is ok